# How to check if a user is logged-in in Angular 8

Tags: angular

As a practice (following video tutorials from udemy) , I'm trying to Guard my link but it gives me some compilation error. Here's my auth-guard.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private route: Router) { }

  canActivate() {
    return this.auth.user$.map(user => {
      if (user) return true;
      this.route.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    })
  }
}
```

Here's my auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  user$: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { 
    this.user$ = afAuth.authState;
   }

  login() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }

  logout() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }
}
```

The compilation error I get from auth-guard.service.ts is "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'." Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are following the tutorial correctly? `user$` is an Observable so you need to subscribe to it. Try using `subscribe` instead of `map`.

Comment: Side effect in map stimulates my spider senses somehow.

Comment: @nash11 Subscribing the observable would return `tearDownLogic` Usage of the map is correct as canActivate expects an observable|boolean|promise. it's just RxJS v5.5.2+ has moved to Pipeable operators. Check my answer for more.

Comment: In your special case, I would try to hold the user value in a BehaviorSubject instead of Observable so the new subscribers are getting the user, too...

Comment: @gaborp How would it help, Please have a look at https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/282#issuecomment-228514876

Comment: @Vikas - yes my bad. forgot about the syntax changes in RXJS 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RxJS v5.5.2+` has moved to **[Pipeable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md)** operators to improve tree shaking and make it easier to create custom operators.
 now `operators` need to be  combined using the `pipe` method
**[Refer This](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-lettable-operators-fe74dda186d3)**
**New Import**

```
import { map} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

**Example**

```
myObservable
  .pipe(filter(data => data > 8),map(data => data * 2),)
  .subscribe(...);
```

Modified Code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private route: Router) { }

  canActivate() {
    return this.auth.user$.pipe(map(user => {
      if (user) {return true;
       }else{
      this.route.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;}
    }))
  }
}
```

Comment: Better to return this.router.parseUrl('/login'), right?

Comment: @BalázsNémeth Nope Look at the signature https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Comment: yes, I was doing that. UrlTree. https://juristr.com/blog/2018/11/better-route-guard-redirects/ how about that?